# Casting constrained generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Quite simply, why does this code fail to compile?

```
public interface IWorld { }
public class Foo<T> where T : IWorld { }
public void Hello<T>(T t) where T : IWorld
{
    Foo<IWorld> bar1 = new Foo<T>(); //fails implicit cast
    Foo<IWorld> bar2 = (Foo<IWorld>)new Foo<T>(); //fails explicit cast
}
```

Since every `T` implements `IWorld`, every instance of `Foo<T>` should match `Foo<IWorld>`. Why not? Is there any way around this? I really don't want to resort to generics to accomplish this.

Comment: Value Types can implement interfaces. Each Value type gets its own implementation of generic code. A `Foo<IWorld>` would use the reference type implementation. So there's a type mismatch there.

Comment: Even if `T` was an interface-implementing value type, `Foo<T>` is still a class, and therefore a reference type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T : IWorld
```

means that T has been implemented IWorld and does not mean that it ONLY has implemented IWorld and EXACTLY is IWorld. It may also has been implemented other interfaces.

However, C# supports this cast in it's later versions. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx (Covariance and Contravariance in Generics)

Comment: Does it? It supports covariance\contrvariance of interfaces and delegates actually...

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to object first

```
Foo<IWorld> bar2 = (Foo<IWorld>)(object)new Foo<T>();
```

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler objection - imagine that instead of `Foo`, this was, say `List`.

Having converted your `List<T>` to a `List<IWorld>`, I can now add some *other* `IWorld` implementing object (say of type `T2`) to a list that is constrained to only contain objects of type `T`. That shouldn't be valid.

So back to your `Foo` object - if it contains any methods that expect to be called with objects of type `T`, I can now call them with *any* object that implements `IWorld` - even if (imagine an additional type constraint of `Foo`) that object would not be an eligible type for `Foo`.

---

My point in the comments re: value types. Again, this may be easier if we talk in terms of `List<T>` - a `List<T>` for value types contains the value types without boxing. If you want a `List<IWorld>` of these same values, each value has to be *boxed* before it's added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with following

```
 Foo<IWorld> bar1 = new Foo<IWorld>();
```

What are you trying to achieve?

If you need to pass `IWorld` instance, you can safely pass `T`, but that is not the case in your code.

**EDIT** (Based on comments)

To cast to `Foo<Array of something>` you can use [Cast](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=enumerable.cast&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx&ei=oELUUOSzHsjXrQePsYCQCg&usg=AFQjCNHdLSSfL8xHvhDg9zmcnYkQd5WpvQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk) or [OfType](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=enumerable.oftype&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx&ei=pULUULzxKsirrAfg2IDQCQ&usg=AFQjCNGD8--Eva8yMkiFrxITkg_Pes56oA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk) depending on your requirement(whether you want to throw or ignore incompatible matches).

If it is .NET 4, it should work automatically due to [CoVariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) feature.

Comment: `Foo` is a wrapper around an array of whatever generic it is passed. I would like this instance of `Foo` to wrap a `T[]` array rather than the base `IWorld[]` array.